# R access to the parallel workers dynamically

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snow

I want to generate multiple parallel r workers that do not need to wait for the other workers to finish their job before getting new jobs.

```
require(snow)

# generate sockets
cl <- snow::makeSOCKcluster(3, type = "SOCK", outfile="")


# here is the function that will be run in parallel
myfunc <- function(x=2)
{
  print(x)
  Sys.sleep(time = x)
  output = sample(x = 1:150, size = 1)
  return(output)
}

# here are the arguments that needs to run in parallel
myfunc_argument <- c(5, 50, 150)

snow::clusterApply(cl = cl, fun = myfunc, x = myfunc_argument)
stopCluster(cl)
```

In this example, the 1st worker needs to wait for the third worker to get a new job.

The next set of inputs will be the outputs (i.e. random numbers between 1 and 150 in this example) of the current run

Comment: Have you tried `clusterApplyLB`? It's a load-balancing version of `clusterApply` that assigns new jobs as previous jobs are complete.

Comment: Unfortunately, the inputs of the next run depend on the outputs of the workers. 
(I tried to update the question accordingly)

Comment: If you can provide an example _without_ parallel processing that illustrated why/what the dependencies are, then it might be easier to help you.  It's not clear what you mean by "1st worker needs to wait for the third worker" and why that is.